# question about differential form on manifold

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

1. If I define a 1-form on  $\mathbf R^{2}$, for example, $\omega_1=-y\,dx+x\,dy$, and integrate $\omega_1$ over a circle $C$ in  $\mathbf R^{2}$,can I say that I define an 1-form $\omega_2=-y\,dx+x\,dy$ only on the circle $C$ and integrate $\omega_2$ over this circle? Are these two integrals same?
2. What is $d\omega_1$ and $d\omega_2$, and where is the difference between these two forms?

Comment: 1. $\omega_1$ is defined on the circle $C$. There is no need to define a $\omega_2$. Do you know how to integrate $\omega_1$ over $C$ ? Hint: line integral . 2. do you know the exterior derivative ?

Comment: @KurtG. I want to know the difference between $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ because I was told that $d\omega_2=0$ since it is a 2-form on 1-manifold which is zero while $d\omega_1$ is not zero

Comment: In fact, I think I see the point now. Yes, on the $1$-manifold $C$ there do exist $1$-forms but not $2$-forms. The $1$-forms on the circle $C$ are *not* restrictions of the $1$-forms in the plane in which $C$  is embedded in. You should look at $\mathbb R^2$ separately from $C.$ Hint : take a parametrization of $C$ and figure out what the tangent space is.

Answer (score 3):

Any $2$-form on a $1$-dimensional manifold must be $0$. The key point is this: If $\iota\colon C\to\Bbb R^2$ is the inclusion map of the circle into the plane, then the restriction of a form $\omega$ on the plane *to* the circle is given by $\iota^*\omega$. Since $d$ commutes with pullback, we always have
$$d(\iota^*\omega) = \iota^*(d\omega).$$

This holds when $\iota$ is the inclusion map of any submanifold $X\subset M$ and $\omega$ is a form on $M$. Moreover, if $\omega$ is a $k$-form on $M$ and $X$ is an oriented $k$-dimensional submanifold, then we typically write
$$\int_X \omega \quad\text{for}\quad \int_X \iota^*\omega.$$